# Deleting not working in React, Error: React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to make a to-do list using React. However, I cannot delete a to-do item. Developer's tools in Chrome only say: React does not recognize the prop on a DOM element. I think filteredList and isDoneList work fine since I can toggle whether to-dos are done or not using them.

Todo.js

```
import styled from 'styled-components';
import Item from './Item';

const Todo = ({ isDoneList, savedList, setSavedList }) => {
  const filteredList = savedList.filter((item) => item.isDone === isDoneList);

  const handleTextClick = (e) => {
    const newList = (filteredList) =>
      filteredList.map((item) =>
        item.id === parseInt(e.target.id)
          ? { ...item, isDone: !item.isDone }
          : item
      );

    setSavedList(newList);
  };

  const handleDeleteBtnClick = (e) => {
    const newList = (filteredList) =>
      filteredList.filter((todo) => todo.id !== parseInt(e.target.id));

    setSavedList(newList);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <ListTitle>
        {isDoneList
          ? `Done: ${filteredList?.length}`
          : `To do: ${filteredList?.length}`}
      </ListTitle>
      <List>
        {filteredList?.map(({ id, text }) => (
          <Item
            key={id}
            id={id}
            text={text}
            isDoneList={isDoneList}
            handleTextClick={handleTextClick}
            handleDeleteBtnClick={handleDeleteBtnClick}
          />
        ))}
      </List>
    </>
  );
};
export default Todo;

const ListTitle = styled.h2`
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 14% 0% 7% 3%;
`;

const List = styled.section``;
```

Item.js

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const Item = ({
  id,
  text,
  isDoneList,
  handleTextClick,
  handleDeleteBtnClick,
}) => {
  return (
    <span>
      <li id={id} isDoneList={isDoneList} onClick={handleTextClick}>
        {text} &nbsp;
        <button onClick={handleDeleteBtnClick}>X</button>
      </li>
    </span>
  );
};

export default Item;
```

part of App.js

```
<>
    <Todo
     isDoneList={false}
     savedList={savedList}
     setSavedList={setSavedList}
     />

    <Todo
     isDoneList={true}
     savedList={savedList}
     setSavedList={setSavedList}
     />
</>
```

Comment: What do you expect the `isDoneList` prop on the `li` element to do exactly ?
`<li id={id} isDoneList={isDoneList} onClick={handleTextClick}>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Set the `id` prop inside the `button` component.

```
<button id={id} onClick={handleDeleteBtnClick}>X</button>
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! seems like i accidently deleted id for button

Comment: sure @Buzz happy coding

Answer (score 0):

At your `handleDeleteBtnClick` function, you're trying to get the event target's id attribute whilst the target is the button and it does not have any id.
Note that the `button` cannot have the same id as your `li`, so one way of solving it is simply swapping the id attribute from one element to another.
The better solution (IMHO) would be passing the id as an argument instead of the event,
`<button onClick={() => handleDeleteBtnClick(id)}>X</button>`.

Also, You are using the same `filteredList` array for both done and undone items which can cause some unexpected results. See [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-borg-q4s8bz?file=/src/Todo.jsx)